# htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) with added variable inside a string

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I'm trying to insert PHP to build dynamic content, but I have some troubles with a form:

```
$content_message = "<p class='notification'>Please type in and confirm your new password.</p>"
    . '<form method="post" id="change_password" action="htmlspecialchars(' . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . '?id=' . $id . '&code=' . $code . ')">'
```

I can't find a way to make `htmlspecialchars` work with `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` together with added variables inside a string.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: `htmlspecialchars(` is PHP take it out of the string. e.g. `action="' . htmlspecialchars(` encode `$id` and `$code` separately otherwise `&code=` will be part of `id` as will `$code`..

Comment: @sebjel any code that you want executed must be taken out of the string. Use an appropriate IDE (something like PHPStorm), it'll help you create cleaner code. You should also try to separate your logic from your HTML. Look into MVC (model, controller, view) and look into creating HTML templates (maybe look at Twig or Blade HTML templating). This should help you create cleaner, more manageable and less buggy code. These are things I wish people told me to look into when I first started and it'll help you a lot in the long run. Also look into microservices (after you understand the rest)

Comment: @sebjel you may also want to simply put `action='page.php'` (obviously whatever page you actually want to go to) and then send the parameters through a PHP session so that the values cannot be easily manipulated through code inspection and it also prevents ugly URLs

Answer (score 0):

Don't sanitise `htmlspecialchars`. Do it this way:

```
$content_message = "<p class='notification'>Please type in and confirm your new password.</p>"
               . '<form method="post" id="change_password" action="'.htmlspecialchars(
               . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]
               . '?id='
               . $id
               . '&code='
               . $code
               . ).'">'
```

Also remember, that browser sends form to the same address which is currently opened, so there is no need to call `action=PHP_SELF`. You can omit action attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send dynamic values then you can easily place with the input hidden tags, & the information will also be secure.

Just like this:

```
$content_message = "<p class='notification'>Please type in and confirm your new password.</p>"
               . '<form method="post" id="change_password" action="" >
               <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" />
               <input type="hidden" name="code" value="'.$code.'" />
               <form/>';
```

And if you want to recieve the value, just check this code:

```
echo $_POST['id'];
echo $_POST['code'];
```

Hope, this may be helpful for you.